# Как найти число + фразу, используя регулярные выражения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Необходимо вывести число, после которого следует фраза million или billion, используя регулярные выражения.
Почему такой синтаксис не даёт положительный результат?

```
text = '199.5 million, 100 million, 80 billion, 1.89 billion, 123 qwerty'
match = re.findall("[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+ \bmillion\b|\bbillion\b", text)
print(match)
```

должен вывести:

```
[199.5 million, 100 million, 80 billion, 1.89 billion]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
import re
text = '199.5 million, 100 million, 80 billion, 1.89 billion, 123 qwerty'
match = re.findall(r"[\d.]+?\s*?[bm]illion", text)
print(match)
#['199.5 million', '100 million', '80 billion', '1.89 billion']
```

Answer (score 2):

Действия:

- Добавил префикс `r`, чтобы `\` не нужно было экранировать (либо без префикса, но добавлять экранирование слешей, т.к. `\\`)

  Без экранирования и с ним:

  ```
  print(repr('\b \\b'))  # '\x08 \\b'
  ```
- Обернул выражения в группы (круглые скобки), но без захвата (добавляя `?:` после скобки)

Попробуйте:

```
import re

text = '199.5 million, 100 million, 80 billion, 1.89 billion, 123 qwerty'
items = re.findall(r"\d+(?:\.\d+)? \b(?:million|billion)\b", text)
print(items)
```

Результат:

```
['199.5 million', '100 million', '80 billion', '1.89 billion']
```